# Android project How to use/merge multiple AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, gradle

I want to split my project to multiple sourceSets, so I want use multiple AndroidManifest.xml to declare current sourceSets's component,util build apk  merge the main AndroidManifest.xml, but there only support one main AndroidManifest.xml setup, so how can I do it?

Why I want to use multiple sourceSets? Because if using multiple modules it compile so slow.

This is my project settings

```
  def moduleDirs = project.projectDir.listFiles()
            .findAll {
        def name = it.name
        // filter all inner's module
        it.isDirectory() && msExtension.modulePrefix.any { name.startsWith(it) }
    }

    Set<File> manifestSet = new HashSet<>()

    Set<String> modules = new HashSet<>()
    def sourceSetConf = { AndroidSourceSet sourceSet ->
        moduleDirs.each {
            def moduleName = it.name
            def dir = sourceSet.name
            sourceSet.assets.srcDirs "${moduleName}/src/${dir}/assets"
            sourceSet.java.srcDirs "${moduleName}/src/${dir}/java"
            sourceSet.res.srcDirs "${moduleName}/src/${dir}/res"
            sourceSet.aidl.srcDirs "${moduleName}/src/${dir}/aidl"

            // each AndroidManifest.xml
            def manifestFile = project.file("${moduleName}/AndroidManifest.xml")
            if (manifestFile != null && manifestFile.exists()) {
                manifestSet.add(manifestFile)
            }

            modules.add(moduleName)
        }
    }

    // for default main sources
    sourceSetConf(android.sourceSets.main)

    // for buildType sources
    android.buildTypes.each {
        def buildType = it.name
        android.sourceSets.getByName(buildType) {
            sourceSetConf(it)
        }
    }

    // for flavor sources
    android.productFlavors.each {
        def flavor = it.name
        android.sourceSets.getByName(flavor) {
            sourceSetConf(it)
        }
    }
```

I see some code from gradle what multiple modules merge, but still no idea how to

> ManifestMerger2
>   ProcessManifest

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple modules via Android Studio. Create dependencies between modules. To make `ModuleA` depend on `ModuleB`, put the following inside `build.gradle` of `ModuleA`:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  compile project(':ModuleB')
  // ...
}
```

This should merge `AndroiManifest.xml` from both modules when buiding `ModuleA`

Comment: But I don't want use multiple modules, because it so slow when compile.

Answer (score 0):

I just use `ManifestMerger2` to do it.

```
 private static void merge(File reportFile, File mainManifest, File... libraryManifests) {
    if (libraryManifests == null || libraryManifests.length == 0) {
        return
    }

    ILogger logger = new StdLogger(Level.VERBOSE)
    Invoker manifestMergerInvoker = ManifestMerger2.newMerger(mainManifest, logger, MergeType.APPLICATION)
    manifestMergerInvoker.setMergeReportFile(reportFile)
    manifestMergerInvoker.addLibraryManifests(libraryManifests)

    println "start merge..."

    MergingReport mergingReport = manifestMergerInvoker.merge()

    println "end merge..."

    if (MergingReport.Result.SUCCESS) {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = mergingReport.getMergedXmlDocument(MergingReport.MergedManifestKind.MERGED)
        try {
            String annotatedDocument = mergingReport.getActions().blame(xmlDocument)
            logger.verbose(annotatedDocument)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e, "cannot print resulting xml")
        }
        save(xmlDocument, mainManifest)
    }
}

private static void save(XmlDocument xmlDocument, File out) {
    try {
        Files.write(xmlDocument.prettyPrint(), out, Charsets.UTF_8)
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e)
    }
}
```